# Add custom View inside Floating Action Button (FAB)

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I want to integrate custom view of this library : [LikeButton](https://github.com/jd-alexander/LikeButton) to be used in FAB. how to do this? is there a way to add custom view in FAB ?

Comment: try this: https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read the library you talk about but check out this [guide](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud862/lessons/4755536308/concepts/48047907400923#) on Udacity, they show how to crate FAB from nothing with all the effects.